ytableau specify boxframe for each \ydiagram
I'm using the ytableau package. I'm writing a document in which I'd like to be able to specify the boxframe for each \ydiagram.
e.g
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxframe = 0.1em]{ytableau}

\begin{document}

First I want a young diagram with boxframe = 0.1em:

\ydiagram{2, 1}

I would like this  next diagram to have a boxframe = 0.3em:

\ydiagram{3, 1, 1}

I don't know how to do this.

\end{document}


However, if I try to do \ydiagram[boxframe = 0.1em]{2, 1} it doesn't work. Thus I am forced to set boxframe globally in the preamble. This means all my \ydiagram's must have the same boxframe.
Is there anyway to have multiple \ydiagram's with different boxframes using this package?

ytableau is a great package, but it has a couple of weak points:

the declarations in \ytableausetup are global;

the default value for boxframe you specify in the options to the package is not kept across the document.


For your application, I'd do similarly to Alan Munn's proposal, but with a few changes, the main one being that after a diagram where the optional thickness is specified, we immediately return back to the default.
I also believe it's better to use explicit lengths rather than relative ones, so lengths in points instead of em units.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[boxframe=0.4pt]{ytableau}

\makeatletter
%% fix a weakness of ytableau
\edef\boxframe@normal@YT{\boxframe@YT}

%% the command for your diagrams
\NewDocumentCommand{\apolloniusyt}{om}{%
  % select the desired thickness
  \IfValueT{#1}{\ytableausetup{boxframe=#1}}%
  % print the diagram
  \ydiagram{#2}%
  % restore the default value
  \IfValueT{#1}{\ytableausetup{boxframe=\boxframe@normal@YT}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

First I want a young diagram with default boxframe:
\[
\apolloniusyt{2, 1}
\]
I would like this  next diagram to have a boxframe = 3pt:
\[
\apolloniusyt[3pt]{3, 1, 1}
\]
Next one with the default boxframe:
\[
\apolloniusyt{2, 1}
\]

\end{document}



The ytableau package provides a setup command \ytableausetup which allows you to set various parameters including the boxframe parameter. So you could just use this selectively before particular diagrams, or (as I've shown here) wrap it into a command that takes an optional argument like the usage you tried:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ytableau}
\NewDocumentCommand{\Ydiagram}{om}{
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}
        {\ydiagram{#2}}
        {\ytableausetup{#1}
         \ydiagram{#2}}
    }
\begin{document}

First I want a young diagram with boxframe = 0.1em:
\ytableausetup{boxframe=0.1em}
\ydiagram{2, 1}

I would like this  next diagram to have a boxframe = 0.3em:

\ytableausetup{boxframe=0.3em}

\ydiagram{3, 1, 1}

I don't know how to do this.

\Ydiagram[boxframe=0.2em]{2,3,2}

\end{document}



As far as I remember, declarations in \ytableausetup are global, so what you use as an optional argument for a tableau will apply to all subsequent ones (unless countermanded). It should possibly be a mandatory argument.
